# Animating Images with a Dial Control (HTML/JavaScript/...)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is what I would like to achieve.

I have a series of images going from dark to white (with all sort of grey levels in the middle). I'd like to have a dial (like a slider) under the frame or over the frame (it doesn't matter). When the slider is to the left, I display the black image, when the slider is to the right, I display the white image and any position in the middle I select an image somewhere in between.

I have limited knowledge of Java Script and HTML5 (hence my question on here) but I am a programmer so I am not afraid of code. I am not asking for a fully developed solution (unless one exists) as I am happy to code it myself, but it would be great if you could give me some hints, directions, ideas for making this work.

- How do I create the slider
- of course more importantly I do I select the right image to display.

I'd like to do something using JS if possible, and not using any external library. Would using a 2D canvas be a solution to both draw the image and UI (the slider)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is used to create a slider of 10 fixed points in HTML5.

```
<input id="barslidesize" type="range"  min="1" max="10">
```

Now you can get the value of the slider with following code:

```
var currentPos = document.getElementById("barslidesize").value;
```

Then you can switch this variable accordingly:
like,

```
 switch (currentPos)
 {
  case "1":
    //do this
    break;
  case "2":
    //do that;
    break;

     .....

  case "10":
    //do neccessary;
    break;
 }
```

Hope this helps you to get started! This is a very basic code.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you do need a very few Javascript. You could do that with a canvas, but I don't think it's the best solution.

Here I place the white image in front of the black one. Then, I use the range to change the opacity of the white image, which renders as grey.

CSS :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .greyslidercontainer {
        padding: 0px;
        background: url(black.png) no-repeat;
    }

    .greyslidercontainer img {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
```

HTML :

```
<div class="greyslidercontainer">
    <img src="white.png" />
    <input
        type="range"
        min="0.0"
        max="1.0"
        step="0.01"
        value="1"
        onchange="this.previousElementSibling.style.opacity = this.value"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: this is a very cool solution and useful however, I mentioned grey images to make it simple, but the images "are" actually files, ... so it's not about fading from white to black, but actually using a different image (as in file) for each "level" of grey (where each image/file is different).